# Jirafe work on magento v1.7?

Tags: magento

We were unable to connect with the Jirafe service. We will try again later, or you can try connecting yourself

Last Status: 400: Bad Request

when jirafe install on magento v1.6, it works ok,but have some problem on v1.7...

i need  some help,please.

sorry for my poor english

Comment: Not a solution, but we've found Jirafe support pretty responsive.  Have you tried contacting Jirafe directly?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instructions in the troubleshooting section here: https://github.com/jirafe/magento-plugin/wiki/FAQ 
and forward us the results to support@jirafe.com.